# Как лучше избежать двух "что"? И на месте ли знаки?

Tags: пунктуация, союзы

> Единственное кулинарное достоинство — салат «Цезарь» почти что
>   настоящий (что великая редкость в Риме).

Comment: А что именно достоинство - салат как факт или его "настоящесть" (и в оригинальном виде, и в виде Вулкана двусмысленность остается)

Comment: Спасибо! Я все ответы и комменты отсылаю автору!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обособляется определение, выраженное прилагательным с зависимыми словами и стоящее после определяемого слова.

А в остальном вариантов не счесть. Например

**Единственное кулинарное достоинство — салат «Цезарь», почти что настоящий (а это великая редкость в Риме).**

Answer (score 0):

В скобках "что" лучше совсем убрать, и без него жить можно. Насчет знаков - запятую бы после "Цезарь", там же идет вводная фраза.

Comment: Как расправиться с лишним *что* - поняла; вводную фразу не распознала...